# Delegating interface methods to various classes

Tags: java, box2d, jbox2d

Even though this is a question includes references to `JBox2d`, its really more of a general `Java` question.
Working on a game in Java, using `JBox2d`. `JBox2d` provides a callback class called `ContactListener`.
The following snippet works fine, when bodies collide in my world I see `Contact begin.` logged to console.

```
// set callback on box2d world
world.setContactListener(new CollisionListener());

// inside game loop, step through physics simulation
world.step(1/60f,  8,  1);

// custom 'ContactListener' definition
public class CollisionListener implements ContactListener{
    private Logger log;

    public CollisionListener(){
        this.log = Logger.getLogger(CollisionListener.class.getName());
        log.info("Registered custom ContactListener");
    }

    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    log.info("Contact begin.");
    }
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {}
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {}
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {}
}
```

However, I'd like to be able to move some collision logic into appropriate classes.
Example, if a `Body` collides with `ConveyorBelt` I'd like to handle logic specific to `ConveyorBelt` inside that class.
So `ConveyorBelt` has it's own `beginContact`, `beginContact`, `preSolve` and `postSolve` method definitions, same for `Rectangle` etc
What would be best way to achieve this?

Class hierarchy ..

```
.
└── InteractiveShape // Parent class, contains 'x, y' position. Many diff classes inherit from it, so i'd like to not have to change this class.
    ├── Circle // sub-class of InteractiveShape
    └── Rectangle // sub-class of InteractiveShape
        └── ConveyorBelt // sub-class of Rectangle
```

Comment: If you can extract the object instances out of `Contact`, then you can have custom contact handlers etc on them and call those.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, when a `Contact` occurs on say a `ConveyorBelt`, how would the `beginContact` method inside `ConveyorBelt` be called?

Comment: Something like `beginContact(Contact contact) {contact.getShape().beginContact(contact);}` - note that I dont know your library, but there will be a similar method to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for hint @MightyPork , used this in the end ..

```
public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

    if (contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData() instanceof ConveyorBelt){
        ConveyorBelt conveyorBelt = (ConveyorBelt) contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
        conveyorBelt.preSolve(contact, oldManifold);

    }else if (contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData() instanceof ConveyorBelt){
        ConveyorBelt conveyorBelt = (ConveyorBelt) contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();
        conveyorBelt.preSolve(contact, oldManifold);
    }
}
```